# CSS properties for StyleableTextField htmlText

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex4

I've got a StyleableTextField that displays very basic HTML. To format the HTML I currently use a Stylesheet declared in AS3.
This works fine, but is rather inefficient for the designers to edit colors and stuff, so I need to include these tags in my main CSS.

The AS3 CSS declaration looks like this;

```
_styleSheet = new StyleSheet();
_styleSheet.setStyle("p", {fontSize:'15',color:'#FFFFFF', fontFamily: 'Courier New', fontWeight:'bold'});
```

This gets assigned to the StyleableTextField using the usual `styleSheet = _styleSheet` way.

The main CSS file is declared in my main application like this: `<fx:Style source="Main.css"/>`.

I already have CSS tags for spark components in my CSS, such like the following;

```
s|TextInput
{
   contentBackgroundAlpha: .5;
   contentBackgroundColor: #202020;
   focusColor: #e1333a;
}
```

However, I need to address the very instance of StyleableTextfield in the CSS (I've got other's in my app, but only this one displays HTML text).

Has anyone got an idea how to do this?
Working on a mobile project btw.

Answer (score 1):

Flex supports a CSS [id selector](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Advanced+Selectors).

```
#instanceID
{
    ...
}
```

or

```
ObjectType#instanceID
{
    ...
}
```

---

I haven't been able to test this thoroughly, but it appeared to work for me:

```
#_objectName
{
    p: pstyle;
}

.pstyle
{
    fontSize: 15;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I could access the textfield like this: ´supportClasses|StyleableStageText#_story´. But how do I set the HTML  CSS properties for the textfields htmlText?

Comment: @Al_Birdy Could you use the `textAreaStyleName` css property? What is a StyleableStageText?

Comment: Sorry, confused StyleableStageText with StyleableTextField. Not sure about the textAreaStyleName, haven't heard about it in relating to the StylealeTextField.

Comment: textAreaStyleName doesn't seem to be applicable for the StyleableTextField.

Comment: @Al_Birdy I edited a possible way in my answer, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Have you tried with the StyleableTextField? Unfortunately it doesn't work for me, I also tried it with setting the namespace for the StyleableTextField first in the CSS (`supportClasses|StyleableTextField#_story`), but not luck either. Do Do I somehow have to set the main stylesheet to the TextField in AS3 first for this to work?

Comment: @Al_Birdy I'm unsure. I'm having issues with mobile projects in FB4.6, so I'm not able to thoroughly test this out. I'll leave my answer here, in case it helps anyone else, but I'm not sure where to go from here.